# How to fix "invalid access to memory location" error?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, native

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr handle = LoadLibrary(@"ItwNidSmart.dll");
        if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            try
            {
                int hr = Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error();
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write("Error: "+ ex.Message);
            }
        }
        IntPtr proc = GetProcAddress(handle, "InitializeModule");
    }
```

I try to load this native C++ library in my Windows 7 x64, but I got this error. I've already built this solution to x86 application.

The error occurs at the call to `LoadLibrary()`.

Comment: As an aside, why do you use GetProcAddress rather than directly P/Invoking, e.g. `[DllImport("ItwNidSmart.dll")]` etc?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the pinvoke.  The DLL is bombing without your help.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually state the exact error message, and which line it occurs on.  Is it possible that you are erroneously linking to the 32 bit version of `ItwNidSmart.dll`?

In fact, your P/Invokes are wrong, which may or may not be the cause of your problem. The most important error is that `GetProcAddress` specifies the procedure name as an ANSI string. They should read:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=true)]
static extern UIntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
```

I'm not sure that these errors are actually causing you problems.

---

**EDIT**

You state in a comment that the failure occurs at the call to `LoadLibrary()`.  If this raises an exception then the only explanation that I can come up with is that the fault lies in the `DLLMain()` of the DLL and not in the C# code.  If the DLL was the wrong bitness, or not found, then `LoadLibrary()` would return `NULL`.

I think to solve this you need to look to the DLL and not the C# code.

Comment: The error occurs when I just call LoadLibrary(). I try to change my P/Invokes, but It still error.